# \b is not matching what I thought it would match

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java regex to match "dept." within the string "dept. no. 2" and not getting back any matches using the following regex "\b(dept\.)\b".

It is my understanding that \b would match spaces since they are not word characters, but it doesn't appear to be doing this. When I add \s* to the regex as in the following "\b(dept\.)\s*\b" I get a successful match.

The way that I read my original regex is match dept. (with a literal period) in between word boundaries. Is that not the correct reading of this?

What stupid thing am I not doing/missing here?

Comment: Show us your code. It is probably a better indicator of what you are doing.

Comment: Word boundaries `\b` match a boundary between a word character and something that is not a word character. So `\bdept\.\b` will not work here. Instead you could use `\bdept\.`

Comment: It should be noted that `\b` is a _zero width assertion_ and does not match any character. It matches a _location between characters_. Other zero width assertions include `$^` anchors, lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: hwnd, thanks Sam also noted this below and this solves my issue. ridgerunner, thanks as well I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\b` matches something along the lines of: `(^\w|\w\W|\W\w|\w$)`.

In other words, a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) next to a non-word character (or at the beginning/end of a String). You are currently trying to use `\.\b` to match ". "; the period will match, but it is not followed by a word boundary (since it is two non-word characters).

This is why you can add in the `\s*` and it will work, because now the word boundary will be matching the space between " n".  I suggest you just use the expression `\b(dept\.)`, since `\.` is very nearly synonymous to `\b` in your scenario (`t` a word character, followed by `\.` a non-word character).

Comment: Of course! It's so simple. SMH, thanks for clarifying that to me, makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: No problem :) please make note of @ridgerunner's comment (which I wasn't aware of previously), that `\b` is a *zero width assertion* that doesn't match any characters.  That is why I said it matches "something along the lines of" (since I always wondered why it didn't actually match anything).  This means you should be able to do `\b(dept)\b\.`.